# How can I find duplicate on one column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL server database,and there are many duplicate in one(RanjePhoneNumber) column.
I am trying to select  rows from a table that have duplicates in RanjePhoneNumber column and they have a same CityId.

My Table:

```
RanjePhoneNumber    ContactId   CityId
776323          280739      7
342261          186372      80
468284          75980       7
776323          101969      9
362875          170242      13
224519          164914      7
342261          203606      55
776323          280733      7
342261          203602      80
```

My expected results:

```
RanjePhoneNumber    ContactId   CityId
776323          280739      7
342261          186372      80
776323          280733      7
342261          203602      80
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group by those two columns:

```
SELECT RanjePhoneNumber, CityID
FROM dbo.TableName
GROUP BY RanjePhoneNumber, CityID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

If you want to select all columns you could use a ranking function:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT t.*, Cnt = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY RanjePhoneNumber, CityID)
    FROM dbo.TableName
)
SELECT RanjePhoneNumber, ContactId, CityId 
FROM CTE
WHERE Cnt > 1
```

If you don't want to find all rows which belong to this "duplicate-group" but only all but the first, use the `ROW_NUMBER` approach [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38454134/284240) has shown.

Comment: This will not give you the different ContactId

Comment: Thank u so muchhhhhhhhhh

Answer (score 1):

```
;with cte
as
(select 
Ranjephonenumber,
contactid,
cityid,
row_number() over (partition by Ranjephonenumber,cityid order by cityid) as rn
from table
)
select 
Ranjephonenumber,contactid,city from cte where rn>1
```

Comment: Thank u so much! :)

Comment: unfortunately it returns Non-repetitive values tooooo!

Comment: if these values repeat more than once "Ranjephonenumber,cityid " it returns them